# How to debug static code block in GEB Page model

Tags: spock, geb

I am trying out GEB and wanted to debug the static code block in the examples. I have tried to set breakpoints but i seem unable to inspect the data that is used in the static content block.

```
class GoogleResultsPage extends Page {
    static at = { results }
    static content = {
        results(wait: true) { $("li.g") }
        result { i -> results[i] }
        resultLink { i -> result(i).find("a.l")[0] }
        firstResultLink { resultLink(0) }
    }
}
```

Any clue on how this normally can be debugged using for example IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the content block is using a DSL and undergoes a transformation when compiled I'm thinking it wouldn't be possible to debug without special support from the IDE, however I hope someone can prove me wrong.

The approach I have been using is to define methods for anything beyond the core content. This provides a few benefits, including debugging support, IDE autocompletion when writing tests, and good refactoring support. The drawback of course is slightly more verbose code, although the tradeoff has been worth it for my purposes.

Here's how I might do the GoogleResultsPage:

```
class GoogleResultsPage extends Page {
    static at = { results }
    static content = {
        results(wait: true) { $("li.g") }
    }

    Navigator result(int i) { results[i] }

    Navigator resultLink(int i) { result(i).find("a.l")[0] }

    Navigator firstResultLink { resultLink(0) }
}
```

Then when writing the test I use a slightly more typed approach:

```
class MySpec extends GebReportingSpec {
    def "google search with keyword should have a first result"() {
        given:
        GoogleHomePage homePage = to(GoogleHomePage)

        when:
        homePage.search("keyword")

        then:
        GoogleResultsPage resultsPage = at(GoogleResultsPage)
        resultsPage.result(0).displayed
    }
}
```